# Woocommerce cash on delivery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am managing a woocommerce eshop that charges 5euros for cash on delivery (cod).

The shipping options are 'local_pickup' and 'wf_woocommerce_shipping_pro' (plugin that separates shipping cost based on postal code).

Id like to avoid cod charge when local pickup is selected, or when the customer uses a postal code that offers free shipping. Woocommerce offers an option to

> Enable for shipping methods

and

> Disable on Free Shipping

but then cod dissapears instead of showing up with 0euros price.

I am using the

> 'WooCommerce Shipping Pro with Table Rate'

plugin to separate which postal codes offer free shipping among others.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

`WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout > Cash on delivery`

And in the field **Enable for shipping methods** add all the other shipping methods except **local pickup**.

To add a different price (other than 0), if you are not familiar with programming you will need this **WooCommerce Pay for Payment** https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pay-for-payment/ plugin. Of course it depends on the WordPress and Woocommerce versions you are using.